# How is the correct way of setting default data in local storage using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have that doubt because I can't put `setDefaultData()` in useEffect within firsts components of the react three or can I?

```
<a>
   "set default data to local Storage" with useEffect 1
    <b>

    "get the default data from local Storage" with useEffect 2
    </b>
</a>
```

because I tried to do that like this:

```
const HomeDashboardContainer = () => {
    const contentList = useSelector((state) => state.contentList);
    const channelList = useSelector((state) => state.channelList);
    const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('this useeffect 1', user);
        // const homeLocation = { pathname: '/home' };
        // FilterManager.setDefaultFilter(homeLocation, props.user.idUser, {
        //  filterValue: { nmSort: 'keyCtContentState' }
        // });
    }, []);
    const props = {
        contents: contentList.items,
        channels: channelList.items,
        isLoadingContents: contentList.isLoading,
        isLoadingChannels: channelList.isLoading
    };

    return <HomeDashboardScreen {...props} />; // useEffect 2 goes inside this component
};

export default HomeDashboardContainer;
```

my problem is that the useEffect of child component activate useEffect first, and do not get any data from localStorage. Someone would know how to repair this issue?

[image: print of parent component printing useEffect 1, and child useEffect 2]

Comment: What part of the code accesses localStorage here?

Comment: @SamGomena the child component